# How to animate the ModelRenderable at the time of placing on the plane?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to play animation (like drop or bounce) on placing of an 3D object (.sfb in my case), but I don't have any idea how can I do that.

I have tried to use ValueAnimator that is working fine for changing its color value, but that's not I wanted.

```
val alphaAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        alphaAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            val animatedAlpha = animation.animatedValue as Float
            modelRenderable.material.setFloat4(
                MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_COLOR,
                Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f * animatedAlpha, animatedAlpha)
            )
        }
        alphaAnimator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
        alphaAnimator.duration = 1000
        alphaAnimator.start()

val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playSequentially(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(modelRenderable, "translationY", 0.0f)
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(modelRenderable, "translationY", 1.5f)
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(modelRenderable, "translationY", 0.0f)
        )
        animatorSet.duration = 600
        animatorSet.start()
```

But this is giving me an error "Could not find property setter method `setTranslationY` on com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should animate the node where the renderable is attached to and not the model itself. The node has a setLocalPosition(Vector3) method which you can use for the ObjectAnimator. So to animate for example the position of your model you should do something like this:

```
ObjectAnimator nodeAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
                yourNode, 
                "localPosition", 
                new Vector3Evaluator(), 
                Vector3.zero(), new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f));
```

Then you can set the duration, repeat count, mode etc. You can also scale and rotate the model over a animation.